# handle request with nginx without proxy-pass or fast cgi

Tags: nginx

I have a nginx with multiple virtual host. one of them is for autodiscover and it only called when someone try to login with his mail in outlook client. this was happen **less than one per month**.

I want nginx run my program to get request and send response. I know that it can handle with `proxy_pass` or `fastcgi` but it's problem is that my program should run and listen for long time without doing anything and it is a overhead for main virtual host.

Comment: Simply point your `location` block to the right folder in the file system and `nginX` will serve the files without any need to proxying or CGI.

Comment: autodiscover is a template file and need to be generated for each request according to request body

Comment: You can try using Lua for that - if your nginX is compiled with Lua support.

Comment: tanks @IVOGELOV. I do same thing after lots of search.